# F# cast invalid

Tags: f#

I have a method :

```
member this.Get<'IAMSOMETHING when 'IAMSOMETHING : not struct>([<ParamArray>] parameters:obj[]) : 'IAMSOMETHING= 
      if typeof<'IAMSOMETHING> = typeof<IProvideAbilities> then
         this._issues :?> 'IAMSOMETHING
      else
         raise(System.NotImplementedException())
```

`this.Issues` is a member. I have an error:

> The member 'Get<'IAMSOMETHING when 'IAMSOMETHING : not struct and
>   'IAMSOMETHING :> Issues> : obj [] -> 'IAMSOMETHING when 'IAMSOMETHING
>   : not struct and 'IAMSOMETHING :> Issues' does not have the correct
>   type to override the corresponding abstract method. The required
>   signature is 'Get<'IAMSOMETHING when 'IAMSOMETHING : not struct> : obj
>   [] -> 'IAMSOMETHING when 'IAMSOMETHING : not struct'.

How can I cast `this.Issues` to `IAMSOMETHING` ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: please learn to format your questions right - this is unreadable

Comment: Also provide full minimum code in order to reproduce your error please.

Comment: Hard to answer when we don't know the type of this._issues field

Comment: Based on the error, it looks like you're implementing an interface that has `Get` method, but your implementation has a different type than the one required by the interface. You'll need to post the details of the interface, otherwise we cannot help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to declare your "parameters" parameter as obj[] instead of obj. The  attribute must be on the last parameter and must be an array.

See documentation [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233213.aspx)

Comment: Sorry,it was a typing error. it is obj[] and not obj